# How can I limit time ago function to under 12 months and post actual date for year or later?

Tags: php

I would like to post the actual date of an article (i.e. April 5, 2015)  if it has been a year or more since its post. If less than a year, I would like to use the time ago function (i.e. 6 months ago).

I've tried commenting out the year in the HumanTiming Time Ago Function (posted by arnorhs) and adding an if/else condition to it

```
$time = strtotime('2015-04-05 17:25:43');

echo 'event happened '.humanTiming($time).' ago';

function humanTiming ($time)
{

    $time = time() - $time; // to get the time since that moment
    $time = ($time<1)? 1 : $time;
    $tokens = array (
        //31536000 => 'year',
        2592000 => 'month',
        604800 => 'week',
        86400 => 'day',
        3600 => 'hour',
        60 => 'minute',
        1 => 'second'
    );

    if($time > $tokens){ 
        echo "April 5, 2015"; 
    } else {
        foreach ($tokens as $unit => $text) {
            if ($time < $unit) continue;
                $numberOfUnits = floor($time / $unit);
                return $numberOfUnits.' '.$text.(($numberOfUnits>1)?'s':'');
         }
     }
}
```

I expect the output to be "April 5, 2015", but it ignores the if/else condition and posts the date as "36 months ago".

How can I achieve the result I'm looking for?

Comment: `$time` is an integer and `$tokens` is an array. You cannot compare those. What is the condition trying to achieve?

Comment: @risingsun - That makes complete sense. No wonder why it didn't work. Lesson learned. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check against the time of one year ago - not against the array `$tokens`. You can get the time of one year ago from `strtotime('1 year ago')`. If that is lesser than `time()-$time` (the current timestamp minus the `$time` timestamp), then the input-time is more than one year ago.

```
function humanTiming ($time) {
    $time = time() - $time; // to get the time since that moment
    $time = ($time<1)? 1 : $time;
    $tokens = array (
        //31536000 => 'year',
        2592000 => 'month',
        604800 => 'week',
        86400 => 'day',
        3600 => 'hour',
        60 => 'minute',
        1 => 'second'
    );

    if (time()-$time < strtotime("1 year ago")) { 
        return date("F jS, Y", time()-$time);
    } else {
        foreach ($tokens as $unit => $text) {
            if ($time < $unit) continue;
            $numberOfUnits = floor($time / $unit);
            return $numberOfUnits.' '.$text.(($numberOfUnits>1)?'s':'').' ago';
        }
    }
}

echo 'event happened '.humanTiming($time).'';
```

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/UH9df

Comment: No need to complicate things by using `if` and `else`, it works but not efficient, if the condition isn't verified inside the loop it won't work it won't return then the function won't break before the final `return`, don't you think ?

Answer (score 3):

using DateTime is way simpler

```php
$now = new DateTime();

$then = new DateTime('April 5, 2015');

$diff = $now->diff($then); // returns DateInterval object or false on failure

if ($diff->y >= 1) {
    // show your date
    echo $then->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
} else {
    // show the interval
    echo $diff->format('%d days ago');
}
```

check the documentation for more info

https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php

Comment: Yep. DateTime is the correct way to work with dates.

Comment: Wow! I really like how concise and effective this is. This is GREAT!!! Thank you so much @talal

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$time = strtotime('2014-01-01 17:25:43');


function humanTiming ($time)
{
    $back_time = $time;
    $time = time() - $time; // to get the time since that moment
    $time = ($time<1)? 1 : $time;
    $tokens = array (
        //31536000 => 'year',
        2592000 => 'month',
        604800 => 'week',
        86400 => 'day',
        3600 => 'hour',
        60 => 'minute',
        1 => 'second'
    );
    foreach ($tokens as $unit => $text) {
        if ($time < 31536000){
        $numberOfUnits = floor($time / $unit);
        return $numberOfUnits.' '.$text.(($numberOfUnits>1)?'s':'');
        }
    }
    return date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $back_time);

}

echo 'event happened '.humanTiming($time);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Everyone's different. I personally like to convert dates into unix timestamps (actual whole numbers) and work from there. Between the function and the function call are some display lines (echos) I added to give you a visual of what's happening. You can remove them, obviously.

```
<?php
//first here's the function
function date_less_year($entered_date_unix)
{
    $difference = time() - $entered_date_unix;
    //31536000 is a 'unix year'
    if ($difference <= 31536000)
    {
        return true; //is less than or equal to a year
    }
    else if ($difference > 31536000)
    {
        return false; //is more than a year
    }
}

/* display in the format you asked for. you can google 'php date' to learn of 
 * different formats you can use
 */
$entered_date_string = '2015-04-05 17:25:43';
$entered_date_to_display = date($entered_date_string);
echo $entered_date_to_display . ' is the date entered<br/>';
//let's turn to a unix timestampe to compare differences
$entered_date_unix = strtotime($entered_date_string);
echo $entered_date_unix . ' is the unix timestamp for entered date<br/>';
echo time() . ' is unix time for NOW <br/>';

if (date_less_year($entered_date_unix) == true)
{
    //do something for less than a year
    echo 'is less than a year!';
}
else
{
    //do something for more than a year
    echo 'is more than a year!';
}
?>
```

Comment: Very interesting concept @ceasar-haze. This is definitely something I can build on as well. Thank you for answering. I appreciate it.

Comment: My first answer. :) 2 things I should also mention, if you store numeric timestamps in sql, use bigints as your data type (they'll just get bigger over time!) and the 'base time' of your app will be that of the server it is running on. So say you use godaddy and their server is in California, your app would likely be in Pacific time. On the client/user level, this can be controlled with JS or having users include their UTF timezone and applying it on the back-end for things like updating events and/or page loads in 'their' time. Good luck!

Comment: Very interesting. :)